# How do I mix the sound from an audio file with the microphone stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add sounds from files to the microphone stream. Is this technically possible?

I tried using different libraries, but I always had problems with the number of channels.

I'm wondering if this can be done without using additional virutal devices?

I tried solving the problem this way, but it didn't work for me

```
import sounddevice as sd
from pydub import AudioSegment
import numpy as np

def play_sound(file_path, device_id=1):

    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(file_path)
    wave_data = np.array(audio.get_array_of_samples())
    sample_rate = audio.frame_rate

    sd.play(wave_data, sample_rate, device=device_id)
    sd.wait()


file_path = '1.wav'
device_number = 1

play_sound(file_path, device_number)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [what you are asking] page for details on how to best help us help you.